# Как организовать общение через сокеты Qt и Java

Tags: java, qt, сокет, клиент-сервер

У меня есть программа на Qt. Она через создание нового процесса - QProcess создает процесс, в котором запускается программа на java. Идея запустить java и наладить общение через сокеты.

При этом в реальности получается так: я запускаю Qt.exe, создаю процесс java, пытаюсь подсоединиться к java программе по сокету, а она еще не запустилась, потому что Qt быстрее запускается. Поэтому происходит так, я пытаюсь в Qt соединиться с сокетом из java, а в этот момент сокет на java еще не создан и получается Qt не соединяется. Получается, что процесс взаимодействия не удается сделать последовательный.

---

Подскажите какие есть механизмы, чтобы сделать так чтобы Qt соединялся с java именно в тот момент когда java уже создалась и все проинициализировала и открыла сокет для соединения. Пока есть мысли сделать задержку потока в Qt на какое-то время, но я понимаю, что это в целом не решение проблемы. Подскажите как быть в такой ситуации.

Comment: Если вы можете подключиться, тогда остается немного - сделайте проверку подключения, наверняка есть метод для проверки доступа и циклом (или через `QTimer) долбите по сокету пока не подключится

Answer (score 2):

На Qt создаем и запускаем сервер ([QTcpServer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html)), а затем запускаем Java-приложение, создаем и запускаем в нем сокет-клиент ([Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)) и долбимся на сервер. Сервер создан раньше и, соответственно, уже работает и ждет соединения от клиентов

Answer (score 1):

Сокеты не очень надежная вещь.

Я бы порекомендовал посмотреть в сторону взаимодействия через шину dbus. В linux шина dbus родная вещь, а для windows есть порты демонов.

В вашем случае обе программы при запуске присоединятся к шине и смогут свободно обмениваться данными